# How to display video a url in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, url

I'm trying to create a form in which a user inserts their youtube code into a field, which is then stored in mysql.

how can i display video?... while fetching data from my database it displays the video url name

How can I do it so that the link is permanently fixed in the php document and the end part is retrieved from mysql in a way that when the page is opened it displays the video correctly?

Very simple stuff when you know how to do it but I don't so I would appreciate if someone could tell me the way of doing this.

without embed only for example this url which will insert into database  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T95zFC4Z2pY" while retiring it by `<?php echo $res['link']; ?>`  is there any other why except embed tag

Comment: Code example? Something you have tried so far? This is not the "You people write code for me" site.

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<iframe></iframe>` tag. I hope it will helpful for you.

Try this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T95zFC4Z2pY">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not giving an example of any code you have tried so far, I will not provide the code, instead I am going to point you in the direction.

Open up the youtube video [Embed Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Then click on 'Share' under the description, then click on 'Embed'. Youtube will give you the code you need to embed your video.